# Routing meant for a subdomain is also being applied to the root domain

Tags: nginx

Consider two websites hosted on the same server: `domain.com` and `foo.domain.com`. I want to start up a monitoring panel for each site on port 5555. Each site has a separate monitoring panel so I need to use nginx to route `domain.com:5555` and `foo.domain.com:5555` to two different places.

Here is the configuration for `foo.domain.com`:

```
server {
  listen 5555;
  server_name foo.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5678;
  }
}
```

While this works fine for `foo.domain.com:5555`, it is also routing `domain.com:5555` to the monitoring panel. This is acting like I had defined `server_name  domain.com foo.domain.com`, but clearly I only defined it for `foo.domain.com`.

The only other nginx configs on the server are for ports 80 and 443. Neither of those configs use any wildcards and explicitly use the full name.

Comment: Did you define two server block? one for domain.com, the other for foo.domain.com

Comment: @Larry.He No, this is the only server block I've defined for port 5555.

Comment: I think you can try to define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nginx` **always** has a default server - if you do not define a default server, it will use the first server block with a matching `listen` directive.

If you want to discourage this behaviour, you will need to define a catch-all server for port 5555.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 5555 default_server;
    return 444;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for more.